# Automate secure CockroachDB deployment on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cockroachdb

I'm currently running through the secure deployment guide for CockroachDB on Kubernetes and while it works exactly as expected, but I'm searching for ways to streamline/automate the deployment.  I'm using `Configs` to deploy, and I would honestly just like to be able to automate the final step (after `kubectl create -f cockroachdb-statefulset.yaml`).  I've been searching around for guides on streamlining deployments, but I haven't come up with much.  Is there a way to complete the following after the config application:

```
kubectl exec -it cockroachdb-0 \
-- /cockroach/cockroach init \
--certs-dir=/cockroach/cockroach-certs
```

Perhaps as part of an `initContainer` in the `cockroachdb-statefulset.yaml` config?

I'm also looking for a way to automate the creation of a db/user account, so any insight there would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look on [kubernetes jos](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

You can integrate this yaml within your deployment, but I do think you need write some wrapper script to confirm the cockroach service is up and health first.

so the job's command coule be:

```
while true;
do
  if `command to check health`; then
    # run kubernetes exec
    exit
  else
    sleep 5
  fi
done
```